# LayerUILib.dll Error in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.3

I am struggling to get rid of the below error,

> the program can't start because **LayerUILib.dll** is missing your computer. try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

***Note***: this error occurs only when I am debugging from VS 2012 for ArcGIS 10.3 'ArcMap' (it is Add-In project).

Comment: Is the DLL actually missing?

Comment: @Hornbydd: no it is not.

Comment: i am very disappointed to see no answer :|